# Partial Converse of Holder's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, lp-spaces

**Holder's Theorem** is the following: Let $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable set. Suppose $p\ge 1$ and let $q$ be the Holder conjugate of $p$ - that is, $q=\frac{p}{p-1}.$ If $f\in L^p(E)$ and $g\in L^q(E),$ then $$\int_E \vert fg\vert\le \Vert f\Vert _p\cdot\Vert g \Vert_q$$

I am trying to prove the following partial converse is true. Suppose $g$ is integrable, $p>1$ and $$\int_E \vert fg\vert\le M\Vert f\Vert_p$$ when $f\in L^p(E)$ is bounded, for some $M\ge0$. I am trying to prove that this implies that $g\in L^q(E)$, where $q$ is the conjugate of $p$. *I am interested in knowing if my proof is correct or if it has any potential.*

Attempt: Assuming this is true, I want to show $\int_E \vert g\vert^q<\infty$. Note that $g^{q-1}\in L^p(E)$ since $\int_E \vert g\vert^{pq-p}=\int_E \vert g \vert ^q<\infty$ (I think this is true since $g$ is integrable - I know it holds when $q$ is a natural number). Take $f=g^{q-1}$ and the hypothesis tells us that $$\int_E \vert g \vert^q\le M\Vert g^{q-1}\Vert_P\\<\infty \,\,(\text{since }g^{q-1}\in L^p)$$so $g$ is integrable.

Comment: This is true.  See for example Royden p. 131.

Comment: @Euler....IS_ALIVE which edition?

Comment: I'm looking at the third edition, but I presume it's in multiple editions.

Comment: @TheSubstitute you can show that $\|g\|_q = \sup\{\int_E |fg| : \|f\|_p \le 1\}$ by doing the cases $q = 1$, $q = \infty$, and $1 < q < \infty$ separately.

Comment: @kobe, where is the $1$ coming from?

Comment: Aren't you including the possibility that $p = \infty$? If you are, then you must consider $q = 1$ -- this corresponds to $p = \infty$.

Comment: @kobe, sorry, I meant the $1$ in $\Vert f \Vert _p \le 1$.

Comment: It's part of the constraint: $\|g\|_q$ is the supremum of the integrals $\int_E |fg|$ as $f$ ranges over $L^p(E)$ such that $\|f\|_p \le 1$.

Comment: Am I supposed to be throwing some machinery (Fatou's lemma, simple approximation) to prove that or does it follow directly from the constraint? I can see how this condition suffices, but I can't clearly see why it is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a correct proof. You want to show that $\int_E |g|^q < \infty$, but then you are using this in the proof. So nothing has been shown.

To write a correct proof, you will have to approximate $g$, as you wrote in your last comment. E.g.set $E_k = E \cap B_k(0)$ (so these sets now have finite measure) and 
$$
g_k(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) \quad (x \in E_k, |g(x)| \le k) \\ 0 \quad \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Clearly $\int_E |g_k|^q < \infty$ for all $k$. Now use the assumption and a suitable limit, e.g. with Lebesgue's Theorem.

Answer (score -1):

**An alternative proof.**

Let $T_g(f):=\int_E f g\,,\, \forall f\in L^p.$

It's clear that $T_g$ is linear.

By the condition $\int_E \vert fg\vert\le M\Vert f\Vert_p$, we see $T_g$ is bounded.

So, $T_g\in (L^p)^*.$

By the **Riesz Representation Theorem for the Dual of $L^p$**(c.f. p. 160, Real Analysis, 4th Edition, Royden), we know there exists an **unique** $L^q$ function $\tilde{g}$ s.t. $T_g(f)=\int_E f \tilde{g}\,,\, \forall f\in L^p.$  By the uniqueness, we conclude that $g=\tilde{g}\in L^q.$

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

The following is the theorem I quoted in my answer.

[image]

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$